# IdentityServer4 Custom GrantValidationResult

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, oauth-2.0, identityserver4

I have been working on IdentityServer4 and in this situation, I use ResourceOwnerPassword grant type

And when I get response from ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator or custom validator it is like below

```
{
   "error": "invalid_grant",
   "error_description": "invalid_username_or_password"
}
```

But I'd like to get response as a custom model, how can I do this ?

Comment: Do you mean you want  additional custom values that will be included in the token response ? like: `context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(
    subject: "818727",
    authenticationMethod: "custom",
    customResponse: new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "some_data", "some_value" }
    });`